# Derby can't create database while running within a webapp?

Tags: tomcat7, derby, javadb

I have this code in a web application (tomcat7):

```
public InitBean() throws UnknownHostException, Exception {
    NetworkServerControl server = new NetworkServerControl(
            InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 1527);
    server.start(new PrintWriter(System.err));

    String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ctc;create=true");

}
```

The intent is to create a Derby database that can accessed from both inside and outside of the webapp. This is an uncommon use-case involving database ETL tools.

I am getting this error:

```
Sep 14, 2015 7:23:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /map threw load() exception
ERROR XJ041: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'ctc', see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM02
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseRdbAccessFailed(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseAccessRdbError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseACCRDBreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.readAccessDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.readSecurityCheckAndAccessRdb(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowSecurityCheckAndAccessRdb(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowUSRIDONLconnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.ctc.service.InitBean.<init>(InitBean.java:40)
```

This is on Windows 7, 64-bit, Java 8, with Tomcat 7.

What could be the problem?

***UPDATE***

The exact same code works fine in stand-alone app (J2SE / JUnit), but it fails under Tomcat / Springframework.

Comment: When it says, "see the next exception for details", do this: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain  Also, what is in the derby.log for your Derby Network Server?

Comment: I did that and the e.getNextException() is null

Comment: XBM02 is SERVICE_MISSING_IMPLEMENTATION, so something is wrong with the configuration of your Derby Network Server. You'll need to learn enough about the Derby server to be able to find its derby.log file, run it interactively, view its console, etc. in order to be able to diagnose this.

Comment: I have no configuration, the server is created in the method shown.

Comment: Have you checked your Tomcat webapp to make sure that it has all the correct Derby jar files? Since you're trying to create the Network Server and also connect to it from the very same web app, you'll need nearly all the Derby jars: derbynet.jar, derby.jar, derbyclient.jar at least. Since your code works correctly outside of Tomcat, you should focus on the configuration differences (CLASSPATH, system properties, etc.) between your standalone environment and your Tomcat web-app environment.